# Is it possible to convert CLOB data to String in Mybatis sql mapper xml?

Tags: spring, oracle, maven, mybatis, clob

I want to receive CLOB data of `CONTENT` column as `java.lang.String` value with only sql mapper definition.

Select query is something like this.

```
<select id="selectById">
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT 
            ID            -- // NUMBER
            , TITLE       -- // VARCHAR2(2000)
            , CONTENT     -- // CLOB
        FROM FAQ
        WHERE ID = #{id}
        ]]>
    </select>
```

Is it possible? I've googled over an hour and realized `<resultMap />` can be the solution.
But, I can't figure out any more.  Please help me.

Comment: What do you expect as the result? POJO? Map? If it's POJO, add the class definition to the question.

Comment: The result I want is Map, of which `CONTENT` value as the type of  `String` NOT `java.sql.Clob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you two approaches.

The first solution is to use `<resultMap />`.
You just need to specify `javaType` for the `CONTENT` column.

```xml
<resultMap type="map" id="faqRM">
  <id property="ID" column="ID" />
  <result property="TITLE" column="TITLE" />
  <result property="CONTENT" column="CONTENT" javaType="string" />
</resultMap>
```

and specify `resultMap` in the `<select />`.

```xml
<select id="selectById" resultMap="faqRM">
```

---

The second approach is to specify the type handler for `CLOB` vs `Object` conversion globally in the config.

```xml
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler javaType="java.lang.Object" jdbcType="CLOB"
    handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.StringTypeHandler" />
</typeHandlers>
```

Then you can simply specify `resultType="map"` instead of defining `<resultMap />`.

```xml
<select id="selectById" resultType="map">
```

---

I should also mention that `java.lang.String` has smaller capacity than `CLOB` (`2GB - 1` vs `4GB - 1` last time I checked).

Comment: Thank you very much, for your explanation.

One question, do I have to declare `<result property="..." column="..." />` for all key-value pairs of result map?

Comment: You're welcome :D In this case, auto-mapping will kick in, so you just need to declare the ones that require extra attributes like `javaType`, `typeHandler`, etc.. But it is usually a good idea to declare `<id />` as it could improve performance ('how much' depends on various factors, though).